# Firebase, Maps error : libc Fatal signal libart.so FinalizerDaemon

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

OS: Android 8.1.0

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0"
```

This is a normal code (as in the examples). I'm writing data to the database.

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("...");
db.child(firebaseUserId).push().setValue(...);
```

I receive an [error](https://gist.github.com/tim4dev/b3ff793d4c33f2ab7917deb650b3b5c3).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because bug reports in Firebase libraries should be sent to Firebase support with full reproduction steps. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Are you doing this `onCreate()` in the App onCreate before calling `super.onCreate()` ?

Comment: @DougStevenson I already sent a report there, maybe someone has a solution.

Comment: Don't vandalise your own question. What's the deal with placing a bounty on it and then trying to remove it?

Comment: @deceze Maybe the cause of errors is NOT in Firebase (realtime). I additionally use Google Maps, Location, Address and related.
I've already rewrite 50% of the application :)

Answer (score 4):

```
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
```

use those it is working for me

don't forget 
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'

Answer (score 3):

Use the same version for all Firebase libs. I solved a similar problem by downgrading all of them to 15.0.0 versions.

Comment: I'm using git. I compiled the version of the application that is on Google Play. And the application worked (until recently). And I got the same crashes. Perhaps the fact is that the changes occur in Google Maps, and it will be a paid service.

However, if no one else has come across this, then the reason is in my application.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error and I updated the all Version of libs same..And update the gradle

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the version. I also face the same issue and i resolved it by downgrading all of them.

after downgrading please ad the this plug in and compile

```
 com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1
```

The version should be the same of your downgrading version

Don't forget to report to firebase. The number of reports helps to resolve this issue by firebase as soon